# What is the simplest way to find an inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -3 & -2 \\
2 & -3 & 7 & 5 \\
3& -2 & 6 & -3\end{array} \right)$

I want to find the inverse matrix of A the simplest way possible.

I know the adjoint method, however, i think it will require too much calculation.

I know the augmented matrix method, this is probably the simplest way to find it, but performing it on a 4x4 matrix doesn't seem to be a very simple task to do.

Is there any other simpler way? If not, what are the tips and tricks to find the row echelon of A? In which row should I start?

Comment: Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix is the way to go in general. When dealing with an integer matrix I like to avoid fractions so I would multiply each row by a number first to make all the numbers in the firs column the same - row 1 and 2 by 6, row 3 by 3 and the last row by 2. The downside is you may get large numbers this way.

Comment: Should I repeat the same process for the next column and so on?

Comment: If you have a graphing calculator, there should be a matrix option. Input the matrix, then make it to the power of -1.

Comment: @amundi12 yea. Once you clear out the entries in the first column you have the second column and you can treat it the same way.

Comment: @Jason Chen unfortunately I am not allowed to access any.

Comment: what is special about this matrix that you want to invent new way to find the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder, but you can calculate the inverse of $A$ using *Schur complement*. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Z&W},
$$
where $X,Y,Z,W$ are square matrices of the same sizes. The matrix $S=X-YW^{-1}Z$ is known as the Schur complement of $W$ in $A$. If both $W$ and $S$ are invertible, then $A$ is invertible too and we have the [matrix inverse formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Background)
$$
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{S^{-1} & -S^{-1}YW^{-1}\\
-W^{-1}ZS^{-1} & W^{-1} + W^{-1}ZS^{-1}YW^{-1} }.
$$
So, to apply this formula to your case, you don't need to calculate any 3x3 or 4x4 adjugate matrices. Instead, you need to compute the inverses and products of a whole bunch of 2x2 matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to actually reduce $A$ to echelon form. You can just eliminate the first column except the first entry to like
$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -3 \\
0 & -1 & 3 & 7 \\
0& 1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right)$$
which is super easy, then you only need to compute determinate of a $3\times 3$ matrix (to me, computing determinate of $3 \times 3$ matrices is always easier than doing Gaussian elimination), which is 
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -3 \\
-1 & 3 & 7 \\
1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right)$$
But behold! There are two $0$'s on the last row, and you only need to compute determinate of
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
-1 & -3 \\
3 & 7\end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Hmm, so operations on the matrix like that does not change the determinant?

Comment: But then again, I have to the adjugate matrix of the original matrix. Which will require me to find lots and lots of smaller determinants.

Comment: @amundi12 Adding a multiple of one row to another row will not change determinant, that's why you reduce to echelon form, whose determinate is just the trace.

Comment: @amundi12 Nah seems adjugate is painful. Sorry I cannot help :(